# Concatenación de datos ListAgg(varchar) a CLOB

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-11g

Necesito concatenar los datos de varias columnas (varchar2) agrupadas por otro campo. Como me paso de los 4000 caracteres he creado columas CLOB para guardar estos datos y después eliminar las columnas varchar2. Para ello he creado una función que usa un cursor donde le he añadido en el select la concatenación usando ListAgg y to_clob pero la función me indica que el resultado de la concatenación de cadena de caracteres es demasiado largo. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?. Utilizo Oracle 11g.

```
DECLARE    

 CURSOR cursorConcat IS  
   SELECT c.expediente_id,
    to_clob(LISTAGG(cem.antec,  chr(13))  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.expediente_id)) antec ,
    to_clob(LISTAGG(cem.dinami, chr(13))  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.expediente_id)) dinami,
    to_clob (LISTAGG(cem.entorno, chr(13))  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.expediente_id)) entorno,
    to_clob (LISTAGG(cem.evolucion, chr(13))  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.expediente_id)) evolucion,
    to_clob (LISTAGG(cem.hechos, chr(13))  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.expediente_id)) hechos,
    to_clob (LISTAGG(cem.historial, chr(13)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.expediente_id)) historial,      
    to_clob (LISTAGG(cem.intervencion,  chr(13))  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.expediente_id)) intervencion,
    to_clob (LISTAGG(cem.procedimiento,  chr(13))  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.expediente_id)) procedimiento,       
    to_clob (LISTAGG(cem.valoracion,  chr(13))  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.expediente_id)) valoracion     
    from centro cem , caso c where c.centro_id = cem.id group by c.expediente_id;


v_datosConcatenados   cursorConcat%ROWTYPE;
v_minimoCentro        number;
BEGIN 

OPEN cursorConcat; 
LOOP
    FETCH cursorConcat INTO v_datosConcatenados;
    EXIT WHEN cursorConcat%NOTFOUND;        

         Select min(e.id) into v_minimoCentro from centro e, caso c where e.id = c.centro_id and
       c.expediente_id = v_datosConcatenados.expediente_id group by c.expediente_id;

       Update centro  cemerg  
       set cemerg.expediente_id = v_datosConcatenados.expediente_id,cemerg.antec_clob = v_datosConcatenados.antec,
       cemerg.dinami_clob = v_datosConcatenados.dinami, cemerg.entorno_clob = v_datosConcatenados.entorno,
       cemerg.evolucion_clob = v_datosConcatenados.evolucion,cemerg.hechos_clob =v_datosConcatenados.hechos
       , cemerg.historial_clob =v_datosConcatenados.historial ,
       cemerg.intervencion_clob = v_datosConcatenados.intervencion , cemerg.procedimiento_clob = v_datosConcatenados.procedimiento
       , cemerg.valoracion_clob = v_datosConcatenados.valoracion where cemerg.id = v_minimoCentro;               


END LOOP;
CLOSE cursorConcat;   
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Proceso terminado y cursor cerrado'); 
EXCEPTION
      WHEN no_data_found THEN        

       raise_application_error (-20001, 'Error occurred: '||DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE, true);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQLERRM); 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ( 'Error raised in: '|| $$plsql_unit ||' at line ' || $$plsql_line || ' - '||sqlerrm);
       ROLLBACK; 
     when others then
     dbms_output.put_line('Otro error');   
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ( 'Error raised in: '|| $$plsql_unit ||' at line ' || $$plsql_line || ' - '||sqlerrm);

        ROLLBACK;
```

Edito: Parece ser que to_clob no funciona, ya que intento hacer una concatenación con más de 7000 caracteres y me da el error.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Por definición en SQL de Oracle la máxima longitud de caracteres es 4000 bytes.
Lo que tiene que hacer recorrer las columnas una a una y concatenar en una variable de tipo CLOB.

Comment: Puede dar un ejemplo de los datos, no es claro lo de "agrupadas por otro campo".